# Fazer dados escritos pelo usuario sejam armazenados em um objeto JS

Tags: javascript, html, objetos

Tenho esse código e queria saber qual a melhor forma de fazer com que o usuário possa apertar em um botão e, a partir disso, armazenar os dados requisitados pela página no objeto JS e, após isso, exibir a mensagem escrita no código. Alguém conseguiria ajudar? Obrigado.

JS

```
var aluno = new Object ()
aluno.nome = document.getElementById("nome");
aluno.telefone = document.getElementById("telefone");
aluno.matricula = document.getElementById("matricula");

aluno.curso = new Object ()
    curso.nome = document.getElementById("curso");
    curso.campus = document.getElementById("campus");
    curso.turno = document.getElementById("turno");

document.write ("Olá " + aluno.nome + ", seu telefone é: " + aluno.telefone + " e sua matrícula é: " +
aluno.matricula + "." + " Você está matriculado no curso " + curso.nome + ", no campus " + curso.campus + 
" durante a parte da " + curso.turno)
```

HTML

```
        <h4>Dados do Aluno</h6>
        <p>Informe o seu nome: <input type="text" id="nome"></p>
        <p>Informe o seu telefone: <input type="number=" id="telefone"></p>
        <p>Informe a sua matrícula: <input type="number" id="matricula"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="curso">
        <h4>Dados do Curso</h6>
        <p>Informe o nome do seu curso: <input type="text" id="curso"></p>
        <p>Informe o seu campus: <input type="text=" id="campus"></p>
        <p>Informe a seu turno: <input type="text" id="turno"></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além de colocar `.value` como informado na resposta do Gabriel, você pode fazer desta forma, chamando uma função e enviado o texto para dentro de uma `div` em vez de usar `document.write`:

```js
function exibe(){
   var aluno = new Object();
   aluno.nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
   aluno.telefone = document.getElementById("telefone").value;
   aluno.matricula = document.getElementById("matricula").value;
   
   aluno.curso = new Object ()
       curso.nome = document.getElementById("curso").value;
       curso.campus = document.getElementById("campus").value;
       curso.turno = document.getElementById("turno").value;
   
   document.getElementById("dados").innerHTML = "Olá " + aluno.nome + ", seu telefone é: " + aluno.telefone + " e sua matrícula é: " +
   aluno.matricula + "." + " Você está matriculado no curso " + curso.nome + ", no campus " + curso.campus + 
   " durante a parte da " + curso.turno;
}
```

```html
<h4>Dados do Aluno</h6>
        <p>Informe o seu nome: <input type="text" id="nome"></p>
        <p>Informe o seu telefone: <input type="number=" id="telefone"></p>
        <p>Informe a sua matrícula: <input type="number" id="matricula"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="curso">
        <h4>Dados do Curso</h6>
        <p>Informe o nome do seu curso: <input type="text" id="curso"></p>
        <p>Informe o seu campus: <input type="text=" id="campus"></p>
        <p>Informe a seu turno: <input type="text" id="turno"></p>
    </div>
<button onclick="exibe()">Exibir dados</button>
<br>
<div id="dados"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vc está pegando o elemento e não o valor dele.
É preciso pegar o atributo value do elemento input, tipo isso:

```
aluno.nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
```

Ai vc coloca todo esse código JS em uma função, adiciona a função em um evento onclick no botão HTML.